# How to convert 1998 USGS map coordinates to current Google Earth coordinates (per changes to North American datums, etc)?

Tags: gps

How to convert 1998 USGS map coordinates to current Google Earth coordinates (per changes to North American datums, etc)?  I looked at other possible questions/answers put forth, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for....

I've got 1998 USGS coordinates for a location/specific object that are considerably off the mark/object if you look at these coordinates on Google Earth - so I know there is some conversion/correction to be done...

any help is appreciated...

Comment: How many meters are the coordinates off? centimeters, 1m or 30-70m?

Comment: Give an examp,e of the coordinates, and where they should belong. Maybe its only a simple conversion error, since 1998 USGS should be nearly WGS84)

Comment: After reading your comment, your question is still confusing. What exatly do you want? Where do you get the coordinates from? from a picture? Or does somebody provide them to you? 1) Post the cooridnate as provided by the data source, and 2)  after your conversion to WGS84. Then 3)  post a google earth screenshot with two markers: where the location should be, and where it is accoridng to google earth.

Comment: See https://files.acrobat.com/preview/92cc620a-3093-4aaf-84c3-4c9f5e5c55f9 -on the 'pinned' Google Earth map, the coordinates given by usgs guy Reiter are ~2,500 ft off NE of where the 'tn mon' dot-inside-box symbol is on the 1985+1998 USGS maps (pinned as 'Town Monument?' on Google Earth map, with line between 2 points).  
So I cannot use this Google Earth method to verify that the 'tn mon' is where the USGS maps indicate it is? or is a correction/correlation to be done?
 
The 3 pix are the mon I think is the 'tn mon' as they show a mon just where the 2 USGS maps put the 'tn mon' symbol...

Comment: You still have bot written how the coordinate was delivered: Is that the screenshot with 72 25 44.46W and 43 01 32.28N? which was delivered by the USGS?

Comment: Yes screen shot is from USGS.

Comment: The screenshot cleary shows WGS84 Datum, have you not seen it? So it is that used by Google and most Tools today. There is no need for coordinate conversion, the error is elsewhere. (For a proof you coul ddemand the coordinates of the crossing of a road nearby, or a church, and this you look up in Google Erath for a proof.)

Comment: What's the current state?, Consider an upvote (arrow up) for my answer below, since it was work to support you, and my answer is correct that the problem i snot related to coordinates (and their conversion)

Comment: The current state is I have re-requested from usgs that the coordinates they gave in their snapshot are correct - I have tried to upvote your good work but I only have a reputation of 11 and one needs to have a reputation of at least 15 to upvote...  will let you know if I get more info/new coords from usgs...  thank you for your help so far.

Comment: New coordinates from USGS (they said they had an error in georeferencing earlier) new coords are:Latitude 43 degrees  -  01 minutes  -  12.8 seconds
Longitude 72 degrees  -  26 minutes  -  07.8 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth uses WGS84 coordinates, so in future please call them WGS84 (coordinates).

USGS 1998, i think use NAD83 (1998) coodinates. Make sure this is correct: Demand the Map Datum of the coordinates you got.

Ask your data provider: "Which **Map Datum** the coordinates are based on?"

According to the link below, and my knowledge, there should be only some centimeters differnce between NAD83 and WGS84:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum#North_American_Datum_1983_and_WGS84

So I think your coordinates could be in NAD27 Datum. (Check with an online NAD27 to WGS84) conversion and look if the coordinates mnow matchm when you use the WGS84 in Google).

In that case you need a NAD27 to WGS84 conversion. This is not easy, that needs so called GRID files.
You will not be able to calculate that yourself, you need a library for coordinate transformations.

**Update**
 you coordinate that you use is totally wrong.
The error is not caused by any Map Datum conversion:

For that location the error between NAD27 and NAD83/WGS84 is 39 meters. (=128ft)
See output of [NADCON](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/nadcon.prl)

```
 NAD 27 datum values:           43 01 32.28000           72 25 44.46000

  NAD 83 datum values:           43 01 32.56771           72 25 42.77644

  NAD 83 - NAD 27 shift values:         0.28771                 -1.68356(secs.)

                                        8.879                  -38.117  (meters)

  Magnitude of total shift:                         39.138(meters)
```

Comment: Alex - the specific coordinates I am seeking to convert are in the "Email with USGS employee..." shared pdf/link below, and a map referring to the 1985 USGS 'tn mon' designation of the dot in the square box is shown in the second shared pdf/link below.  Thanks again for your help. Pat
Email with USGS employee re 'tn mon' coordinates:
 
https://files.acrobat.com/preview/0b592853-5c4b-4ccd-b98f-505c76369b3e
 
 
 
 
1998 and 1985 USGS maps, to see 'tn mon' label: 
 
https://files.acrobat.com/preview/83b8b3c1-9e1b-48dd-b0f8-db5fcddfa741

Comment: The longitude 72 25 44.46W as seen in the screenshot is already in WGS84, converted to DMS lat,long: 43.0256333, -72,429016 .  I still have not understood what you want, I hope you have. Or is the tool in the screenshot your tool, that does not work, which you would like to fix?

Comment: What means that 7,5 visible on the photo of the monumentum?

Comment: That is one of the mysteries I am trying to solve, along with where it is located - I am in a dispute with others as to whether this indeed is the 'tn mon' or not...

Comment: Probabyl it is not. It is simply another stone, Proof with my tip above, let you give a coordinate at the next church or a street crossing, that you will look up in Google Maps and Google Earth. Next time use a GPS device to make sure you are at the right place (If you have made the photo) (But GPS in Woodd may be off by 100 or more meters.)